# Why the expectation of y-E(y|x) multiplied by any function of x is zero

Tags: mathematical-statistics

One of my basic stats lecture slides has this statement as a standalone bullet point with no explanation:

If $u=y-E(y|x)$ then $E(g(x)u)=0$ provided that $E(|g(x)u|) < \inf$ and $E(|u|) < \inf$

Could somebody please show me how this is derived / attained? I've been going in circles, and have no idea what to Google as this result has no meaningful name attached to it on the slide.

Comment: Would it make more sense if $E(u) = 0$?

Comment: I can see how above is true, I'm however unsure as to how to go from $E(g(x)u)$ to showing it should equal zero. Naturally I'd expand $E(g(x)u) = E(g(x)y)-E(g(x)E(y|x))$, but now since I don't know the relationship between $g(x)$ and $E(y|x)$ or $y$ I'm reluctant to go any further with it - as in to go $E(g(x))E(y-E(y|x))$. Can I do that? If so, why?

Comment: What exactly must you know about $g(x)$ to factor it out in that way?  In the expectation being considered, what variable is being integrated over?

Comment: To factor it out, $E(y|x)$ would have to be independent of $g(x)$, hence $x$, but so far since it is conditioned on $x$, I would guess that it is dependent on $g(x)$ - then again, I'm just getting started at getting my head around this

Comment: Think about that outside $E$ in $E(g(x)u)$.  Write it in full integral notation.  What is the differential $d(\text{variable})$?

Comment: I believe that should be $dx$, leading me to $y\int g(x)f(x)dx - \int g(x) E(y|x)f(x)dx$. Now, as $E(y|x)$ is a function of x, I can't simply take it outside of the integral... unless its $dy$ in which case this is trivial, but then I don't understand how we know its $dy$

Comment: This is the deep flaw in the $E$ notation.  $u$ is a function of $y$ alone, so  give it a try with $dy$.

Comment: That works just fine - but $g(x)$ is a function of x, so how do I know that the expectation is of $y$?

Comment: When you did it with a $dx$, $y$ was a function of $y$ alone, so you could ask the same question in reverse.  What did you do then?

Comment: I assumed that since $g(x)$ was a function of x, and $u$ was a function of both y and x, x was the logical choice.

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense, and that's my point about the $E$ notating causing more ambiguity than necessary.  In any case, when you condition like $E(y \mid x)$, you are usually thinking as if the thing being conditioned upon, $x$ in this case, is fixed and known.  So in almost all situations, $u$ is thought of a function of $y$.  It took me way longer than I want to admit to figure this out.

Comment: But I guess the g(x) is the "addon" tagalong function, and the question is mainly about u, so I should have thought of y first. I'm not sure of the etiquette of stack exchange. Should I remove this question as it is trivial?

Comment: No need for that.  Why don't you summarize the discussion in an answer and accept it.  I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Thanks! Its quite embarrassing how much I'm struggling with some of these trivial problems.

Comment: Probability theory has it's own language and conventions.  It gets easier once you get used to them, and in the meantime you will occasionally be confused.  That's how it was for me anyway.  So it goes.

Answer (score 4):

As the expectation $E(g(x)u)$ is in terms of $y$, the $g(x)$ can simply be taken outside of the expectation, leaving $g(x)E(u)$. $$E(u) = E(y-E(y|x)) = E(y) - E(E(y|x)) = E(y) - E(y) = 0$$

Hence $g(x)E(u) = 0$ under the conditions in question.

Comment: Why, exactly, are the two finiteness conditions needed?